# Perform a Loop on a function

Tags: shell-script

I'm trying to perform a loop when an admin runs a script and it prompts him how many users he wants to add, if he types in 2, I want a loop to run on the portion that asks for the username and password to be put in.  For example, if the admin puts in 5, it would ask him a username and password 5 times.  Is this possible, please let me know.  This is for a class, and I'm new to scripts so it might be horrendous looking

```
#!/bin/bash

read -r -p "Hello Titan, How many users would you like to add to the mainframe : " input
    if [[ $input =~ ^[1-9]$ ]] ; 
    then
        echo "Thank you Titan, Now Adding $input User(s) to the mainframe"
        **if [[ $input == 1 ]] ; then
        read -p "Enter Username : " username
        read -p "Enter password : " username
        egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd >/dev/null
            if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
                echo "$username exists!"
                exit 1
            else
                pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "password")' $password)
                useradd -m -p "$pass" "$username"
                [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "User has been added to system!" || echo "Failed to add a user!"
            fi
        else
            echo "Can not add users"
        fi**
    else

        echo "Amount of users invalid"

    fi
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the code to be repeated into a function:

```
#!/bin/bash

add_user () {
    if [[ $input == 1 ]] ; then
        read -p "Enter Username : " username
        read -p "Enter password : " username
        egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd >/dev/null
        if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
            echo "$username exists!"
            exit 1
        else
            pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "password")' $password)
            useradd -m -p "$pass" "$username"
            [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "User has been added to system!" ||
                echo "Failed to add a user!"
        fi
    else
        echo "Can not add users"
    fi
}

read -r -p "Hello Titan, How many users would you like to add to the mainframe : " input
if [[ $input =~ ^[1-9]$ ]] ; then
    echo "Thank you Titan, Now Adding $input User(s) to the mainframe"
    for((i=0;i<input;i++)); do
        add_user
    done
else
    echo "Amount of users invalid"
fi
```

Comment: Thank You!  I didn't quite work the way I wanted it to, but with your help i was able to complete the command so it produced the exact syntax I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

With your Help I was able to get the right coding thanks Hauke!

```
read -r -p "Hello Titan, How many users would you like to add to the mainframe : " input
if [[ $input =~ ^[1-9]$ ]] ; then
        echo "Thank you Titan, Now Adding $input User(s) to the mainframe"
        for ((i=0; i<input; i++)) ; do
            read -p "Enter Username : " username
            read -p "Enter password : " username
            egrep "^$username" /etc/passwd >/dev/null
            if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
                echo "$username exists!"
                exit 1
            else
                pass=$(perl -e 'print crypt($ARGV[0], "password")' $password)
                useradd -m -p "$pass" "$username"
                [ $? -eq 0 ] && echo "User has been added to system!" || echo "Failed to add a user!"
            fi
        done
else
    echo "Amount of users invalid"
fi
```